# Get the last non empty column value of every row in the spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to extract the last non empty value in the column of every row in a spreadsheet
I prefer to use arrayformula if thats possible

```
=transpose(ARRAYFORMULA(COLUMN(B2:ZZZ)))
```

Here is the spreadheet, that I have tried
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14iTSYnyKycccVvULCSCyG6cRFNdRoY82YzWSyises2c/copy

[image: image.png]

Comment: Why "prefer to use arrayformula"? What's wrong with the simple and efficient `=IFNA(LOOKUP("Ω",B2:ZZZ2),"")`?

Comment: The list keeps increasing from external source and its difficult for me to drag the formula down each time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In A2 try

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(regexextract(trim(transpose(query(transpose(B2:1000),,rows(B2:1000)))), "[^\s]+$")))
```

[image]

---

In case there are spaces in the data, try

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(substitute(regexextract(trim(transpose(query(transpose(substitute(B2:1000, " ", "~")),,rows(B2:1000)))) , "[^\s]+$"), "~", " ")))
```

[image]

and see if that helps?

Answer (score 2):

Another solution (in A2):

```
=index(iferror(substitute(split(trim(transpose(query(substitute(sort(transpose(B2:I),sequence(columns(B2:I)),)," ","❄️"),,9^9)))," "),"❄️"," ")),,1)
```

This reverses the range and uses query smush + split + index(,,1) to return the first one. The SUBSTITUTE()s are there to account for possible spaces.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to simply list the last non-empty values for each row that has a value in Column A, you could use the following formula in a separate tab in cell A1, or in the first cell of another column of your choice. I simply added `sort` to the formula that @ztiaa came up with.

```
={"Expected Values";sort(index(iferror(substitute(split(trim(transpose(query(substitute(sort(transpose(Sheet1!B2:I),sequence(columns(Sheet1!B2:I)),)," ","❄️"),,9^9)))," "),"❄️"," ")),,1))}
```